# C# - How to get inactive assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm trying to create instance of a class based on string classname. I'm looking through every assembly and if assemlby contains the type, I create it.

```
        object[] parameters = null;
        Type type = Type.GetType(classname);

        if (type != null)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameters);
        }

        foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            type = assembly.GetType(classname);

            if (type != null)
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameters);
            }
        }
```

The thing is, when you don't use anything from the assembly it doesn't load and is not availible in

> AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()

. 
Is there a way to access all, in project, included assemblies? Or do I have to just Call something from the assembly to make it load?

Comment: Calling something in the assembly is one way, manually loading all assemblies in your plugin folder (or similar) is another, listing them in app.config and then manually loading the ones listed there is a third, there's plenty of ways, but none automagical.

Comment: Why not provide an assembly-qualified name to start with? No need to search then.